# How to get starting time of a File Explorer window?

Tags: windows, shell, com, autohotkey

I'm building Autohotkey script in order to take a backup of opened File Explorer windows list.
I'm looking for a way in order to get starting time of each window *(time when I've opened the window)*.

I've this function:

```
list_opened_folders(byref file_explorer_windows) {
  ; file_explorer_windows := [] ; array of file_explorer_windows

  for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows {
    file_explorer_windows[a_index] := {}
    file_explorer_windows[a_index].path := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
    file_explorer_windows[a_index].id := window.HWND
    file_explorer_windows[a_index].started_time := window.Document.Folder.Self.Time ; Line I'm trying to add (I know this is invalid but to illustrate my idea)
  }
}
```

Comment: A list of what information is available can be found  [here at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)).

Comment: @KenWhite I see it's not available. Thanks anyway. May be I need to try another approach that Autohotkey itself logs the opening time of each window.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#Persistent
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

file_explorer_windows := {}

SetTimer, GetExplorer, 100

GetExplorer:

    Process, Exist, Explorer.exe
    If ErrorLevel 
    {

        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows { 
            if (file_explorer_windows[window.HWND]["id"] == "") {
                file_explorer_windows[window.HWND] := {id: window.HWND
                                                     , path: window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
                                                     , start: A_NowUTC}
            }
      }
    }
Return
```